# java path from top to the bottom of the grid

Tags: java, recursion, path-finding

I have seen this question quite often, but it usually deals with finding only the number of the possible paths a robot can take. So, the question is: there is NxN grid, and a robot is standing at the top of the grid. In one move, it can move only to the right or to the bottom.

Now, I would like to print out all the possible paths a robot can take. Given an NxN matrix,
starting at [0][0], it has to finish at [N-1][N-1]. What I have tried is a simple recursive solution:

```
public static void getPaths(int[][]A, int i, int j, ArrayList<Integer> path, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths) {
    int n = A.length;
    if (i>=n || j>=n) return;
    if (i==n-1 && j==n-1) {
        path.add(A[i][j]);
        allPaths.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(path));
        return;
    }
    path.add(A[i][j]);
    getPaths(A, i, j+1, path, allPaths);
    getPaths(A, i+1, j, path, allPaths);

    path.remove(path.size()-1);
}
```

but I don't know where to "reset" the current path.

Let's say, given
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

matrix, my solution would give
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: what about all of the other solutions? [1,4,5,6,9],[1,4,5,8,9],[1,4,7,8,9]?

Comment: nope, it always prints [1,2...] something. It does produce 6 paths altogether, as expected, but each path is for 1 longer than the previous one. I don't know where to "reset" it.

Comment: You could try a purely functional solution with objects that don't change (create new lists instead of modifying existing lists) - then you wouldn't have to "reset" anything.

Comment: "each path is 1 longer"? I don't get it. If your solution produces 6 paths then show us all 6 paths, not just 3.

Comment: @RobinGreen where would you create a new list? at what point in the code?

Comment: @Maggie, if the robot can only move to the right or down how is [1,2,3,5,...] a solution?

Comment: Of course it's not! my code does not produce the correct result, that was the entire point of the question :)

Comment: Oh okay. BTW, you are counting paths multiple times here and this will give you an O(2^n) time complexity since every node has two possible paths (right, down). You could speed this up tremendously to O(n^2) by using memoization/dynamic programming.

Comment: I am more interested in understanding recursion right now, than in optimal algorithm for path finding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem. The output is

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6, 9], [1, 2, 5, 6, 9], [1, 2, 5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 5, 6, 9], [1, 4, 5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7, 8, 9]]
```

.

```
public class Main {

    public static void getPaths(int[][]A, int i, int j, ArrayList<Integer> path, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths) {
        int n = A.length;
        if (i>=n || j>=n) return;

        path.add(A[i][j]);

        if (i==n-1 && j==n-1) {
            allPaths.add(path);
            return;
        }
        getPaths(A, i, j+1, new ArrayList<>(path), allPaths);
        getPaths(A, i+1, j, path, allPaths);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        getPaths(new int[][] { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}, 0,0, new ArrayList<Integer>(), allPaths );
        System.out.println(allPaths);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. so stupid I didn't see it at first.

Comment: you really don't need to pass allPaths as part of your recursion btw, make it sit outside at the class level

Comment: @pmminov you're right but in that case, you need to put this method as a non static in a class which holds allPaths as a member for proper use in an eventually multithreaded program.

Comment: I think that in the last call of getPaths, the duplication of path is not needed. So getPaths(A, i+1, j, new ArrayList<>(path), allPaths) can be replaced by getPaths(A, i+1, j, path, allPaths). I modified the code.