# Recursion to print all paths in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I came across a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883097/java-path-from-top-to-the-bottom-of-the-grid). Can someone please explain how is this working. In particular, one of things that I am not able to understand is the recursive call. In one of them `new ArrayList<>(path)` is passed while in other simply `path` is passed. Why ? Between the solution is working all right.

```
public class Main {

    public static void getPaths(int[][]A, int i, int j, ArrayList<Integer> path, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths) {
        int n = A.length;
        if (i>=n || j>=n) return;

        path.add(A[i][j]);

        if (i==n-1 && j==n-1) {
            allPaths.add(path);
            return;
        }
        getPaths(A, i, j+1, new ArrayList<>(path), allPaths);
        getPaths(A, i+1, j, path, allPaths);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        getPaths(new int[][] { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}, 0,0, new ArrayList<Integer>(), allPaths );
        System.out.println(allPaths);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy of the path so far is created and passed in the first recursive call so that further entries can be added to the path. We do not need to pass it in the second call as whatever entries will be added as a result of second call are part of the first call's path.

Answer (score 1):

They represent two different paths from the current one. So, new ArrayList<>(path) is used to create a copy of the current path in one direction and just path is passed to complete the current path on the other direction.

Essentially because you want to complete two different pahts, you can't use the current one to insert two different paths in the same array. So you pass the copy in one of the calls, to have that path in a different memory area so both paths that separate on the current point can be calculated independently.